# ArrayAdapter , check if checkbox is checked and remove the row after animation

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, android-checkbox

Hello how can I check if a checkbox is check, and if it is check
how can I remove the row in question ?
thank you

ArrayAdapter :

```
public class Todoadapter extends ArrayAdapter<Todo> {


    private Context mcontext;
    int mresource;
    public Todoadapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<Todo> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.mresource=resource;
        this.mcontext= context;


    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        String todo = getItem(position).getTodo();

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(mresource,parent,false);
        CheckBox box = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        box.setText(todo);

    return convertView;
    }

}
```

My main activity :

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView view = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);

    Todo eat = new Todo("Eat ");
    Todo sleep = new Todo("Sleep");

    ArrayList<Todo> todolist = new ArrayList<>();
    todolist.add(eat);
    todolist.add(sleep);

    Todoadapter adapter = new Todoadapter(this,R.layout.custom_adapter_layout,todolist);
    view.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

}

My XML

[image]

[image: Todo] [image]
The problem is the row still visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the approach, I don't know exactly how you are populating your list and if you are using the Recycler View, but this should be the body for what you want.

```
box.setText(todo); 
box.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(box.isChecked()){
                    //Delay to see animation
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            objects.remove(getItem(position)); //Your object list where you have the itens
                            notifyDataSetChanged(); //If you are using a recycler view.
                        }
                    },300); //adding 0.3 sec delay
                }
            }
        });
return convertView;
```

EDIT:
For get your list, probably you should do something like this:

```
private List<Todo> objects = new List<>(); //NEW
private Context mcontext;
int mresource;

public Todoadapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<Todo> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.mresource=resource;
    this.mcontext= context;
    this.objects = objects //NEW

}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer

Is <your_list>  my arraylist ? 

I have this :   ArrayList<Todo> todolist = new ArrayList<>(); in my main activity and I've put "todolist" instead of your_list but it doesn't work,

I added main activity in my main post

Comment: @Blebhebhe look my edit, I change <your_list> for object. I think should work now.

Comment: EDIT : SORRY EVERYTHING WORKS !! I forgot box.setText(todo);

Comment: Great, don't forget to put as Right solution, glade I could help @Blebhebhe

Comment: When I click wherever on the row it does remove but how can I remove  only when I " check " the checkbox ?

I tried : if (box.isChecked()){
            objects.remove(getItem(position)); 
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

but it doesn't work

Comment: can you post your Xml code from the item? where you have your box.

Comment: I put it in the main post since it's messy here

Comment: But your checkBox Width is "match_parent", so your check box is in the whole space. Thats why when you click it happens, but I will edit the answer with a possible solution inside the "onClick"
@Blebhebhe

Comment: Oh sorry, I've been waiting and didn't notice that you edited ,
I changed the width and it does remove only when I click on the checkbox !
but I  want to see the " red tick " before it gets removed, isn't it possible ? :s

Comment: Thank you very very much , really really appreciate it. 
and sorry for being picky, wish you a happy new year